# Prevent insert duplicates in remote DB

Tags: oracle, error-handling, insert

I have table A1 in server S1 and table A2 in server S2.

Those tables have the same structure and I want to apply an `INSERT` statement from A1 to A2 by `db_link`.

The issue is, that I want to prevent failure of the whole statement because of unique constraint or unique index exceptions.

I tried to use `DML-ERROR-LOGGING` but it just can't work with db_link (the exception raised for the statement).

I also checked the option of `ignore_row_on_dupkey_index` HINT,
but the same problem on remote DB.

Is there any solution for that issue?

I'm using oracle 11g version.

Comment: If you do it row-by-row and handle the exception, you can do it

Comment: It's about 400M rows...  row by row has bad performance.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be slower but since you don't want row-by-row...

```
INSERT INTO T1 (c1, c2, ...)
SELECT c1, c2, ...
FROM T2
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT *
     FROM T1 
     WHERE T1.c1 = T2.c1 AND . . . );
```

Other than this, another method would be: removing constraints, do dirty insert, delete duplicates, reinstate constraints

Answer (score 0):

Finally,

I found that apply the insert when the remote table is the target,

and the local is the source is not working.

But, execute the command when the remote table is the source and the local is the target - is working normally with the error logging.

(we need to swap the directions of the db_links and run the command from the other server).

example:

```
--- use that:
-- connect to S2

-- run
insert into A2 select * from A1@S1.. log errors...;

--- instead of that:
-- connect to S1

-- run
insert into A2@S2 select * from A1.. log errors...;
```

Comment: How this is a solution? You just have constraints in one table and not another. You original problem was *"how to insert records and prevent duplicates from error out"*. Not serious

Comment: You didnt understand the solution. The insert is in the same direction,  source data in a1, and target table in a2. The change is which server is the one you running rhe command from-the local,  and which is the remote server. In that way if you have matching dblink,  you can do it. Watch the example of the solution - the target and source like in the original problem,  but the position of the dblink is different.